# Using grep to remove specific objects in GCS with gsutil -rm

Tags: grep, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a bucket with many objects, and I can successfully use grep to take the specific objects and output them into a text file. I want to use gsutil -rm and read the text file line by line and remove the corresponding object in gcs, but how can I go about doing this?

Or is there a way to directly remove objects from GCS using gsutil -rm and grep? Thanks!

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: So let's say I have objects named hello.jar, hello2.jar, hello3.jar in a bucket. I'd want to do something like  gsutil rm gs://my_buck | grep hello.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rewrite your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you output the list of objects to remove to the file remove.txt, you could use this command to remove the named objects:

gsutil -m rm -I < remove.txt

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see this as an option on the documentation for gsutil rm, but good to know =)